# moveTaskToBack and restore to front prevorious application

Tags: android

I have a small question. My application sometimes reorders to front when some my events fires, but i want after 5-10 seconds move it to back and restore previous application which was active before. How can i do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can start a worker thread in background and fire the intent with the action specified in your application(you need to specify a intent action for your application that has to be restore).